# How do you normalize this wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

I have a basic question in elementary quantum mechanics:

Consider the Hamiltonian $$H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\partial^2_x - V_0 \delta(x),$$ where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac function. The eigen wave functions can have an odd or even parity under inversion. Amongst the even-parity wave functions, one represents a bound state and the rest are extended states making a continuum spectrum. The wave functions for the extended states with energy $E_k = \hbar^2 k^2/2m$ are
$$\psi_k(x) = N_k \left(e^{-ik|x|} + b_k e^{ik|x|}\right), \quad k\geq0$$ with $b_k = \frac{iV_0}{2k}+1$ and $N_k$ is the normalization factor that renders $$\int^\infty_{-\infty} dx ~ \psi^*_{k'}(x) \psi_k(x) = \delta(k-k').$$ My question is, what is $N_k$ (up to an irrelevant phase factor)?

I proceed as follows but run into a problem. First, from Schrodinger equation I could obtain that $$(E_k - E_{k'}) \int^L_{-L} dx ~ \psi^*_{k'}(x) \psi_k(x) = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\int^L_{-L} dx ~ \partial_x \left(\psi^*_{k'}(x)\partial_x \psi_k(x) - \psi_k(x) \partial_x \psi^*_{k'}(x)\right).$$ Here $L$ shall be sent to infinity. Then I substitute the expression of $\psi_k$ and $\psi_{k'}$ and end up with $$\int^L_{-L} dx ~ \psi^*_{k'}(x) \psi_k(x) = 2i|N_k|^2\frac{b_kb^*_{k'} e^{i(k-k')L} - e^{i(k'-k)L}}{k-k'},$$ where I have dropped terms with $e^{\pm i(k+k')L}$, which are supposed to vanish in the limit $L$ going to infinity. I got stuck here. Would anybody show me how the wave functions are orthogonal at first? Thanks.

Comment: Check the normalization condition, one of the limits should be $-\infty$. Also the second equation should not have any variable $z$, just $x$ if this is a 1-dimensional problem. To normalize you don't need the Schrödinger equation just the norm square of your $\psi_k$, however unbounded states modelled as plane waves will have an unbounded norm.

Comment: Not sure you can figure out the correct "normaliztion" constant in this way.  Instead, use the following identity: $\delta(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx}dx$.